# Question regarding for the learning path in salesforce

Tags: sales-cloud

follow this link to create a report-https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customhelp_lex_learning_monitor.htm&type=5

I have created the record type in the Learning Content Progress.
and I want to create a report in this report type to track the user's progress
so the problem is that when I drag the user's Full name (field) it shows an error like this
could you please help me to solve this error?

[image]

Comment: I note that feature is in beta, so this could be a bug in the platform. Have you tried using first and last names instead of full name?

Comment: yes, I have tried but it shows the same error.

Comment: I suggest you try to open a case with Salesforce, though being a beta release feature may mean they will not provide support...

Comment: Based on Salesforce backend logs, I see the stacktrace id `619470827` points to `java.lang.NullPointerException`